# Python class error TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, class, os.walk

I have a python class as following.

```
class copyingfiles():
    @staticmethod
    def __init__(self, x=[], y=[], z=None, i=None):

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self. z = z
        self.i= i
    @staticmethod
    def mover(self):
        x = self.x
        y= self.y
        z = self.z
        i= self.i
        for sam in x.keys():
            for pids in y:
                PID = pids.split('_')[1]
                if sam in pids:
                    destination = z + "/rep/" + "study/" +  id  + "/" + sam + "/rh/"+ "fg/"
                    if not os.path.isdir(destination):
                        pathlib.Path(destination).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
                    for files in fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(i), pat="*.gz"):
                        if sam in files:
                            shutil.copy(os.path.join(i,files), os.path.join(destination,files))

                return(destination)
```

Where x=[], y=[] are dictionaries and  z=None, I=None are paths.

And I tried to call the function within my class `copyingfiles` as following,

```
testInstance = copyingfiles()
testInstance.mover(x, y,z,i)
```

It is throwing following error,

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-7da378685d71> in <module>
----> 1 testInstance = copyingfiles()
      2 testInstance.mover(x, y,z,i)

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I have theoretical understanding of python classes. however, never tried it. So any help would be great!

Comment: This is an oddly complicated first foray for someone who is completely new to python classes.

Comment: read what `staticmethod` does: it cannot go with a `self` argument. In fact, it is rarely used in python

Comment: Ok, so the function inside the class is fine and I am able to get I need. I have several such functions now it is the time to move everything to a global class. I have theoretical understanding of python classes . Just that I have never done it before

Comment: I used `staticmethod` because I saw it can be used if you want to call a class without the help of a variable

Comment: The whole *point* of `__init__` is that it is called (by Python, rather than explicitly by you) on a newly created instance. You don't need to fully understand this now, but for future reference, `o = copyingfiles()` is really something like `o = copyingfiles.__new__(); o.__init__()` behind the scenes.

Comment: `staticmethod`is used when you want to define a method that does not depend on the class or instance attributes (which only serves for keeping order, since you can use a function for that).

Comment: Don't edit the code after people have answered you, now the answers are all wrong and don't make sense.

Comment: ok, however even after making the changes you defined in answer session I am getting what I need

Comment: The code in the question does not produce the error in the question.

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the `@staticmethod`, those are used when you don't want to link the method to an instance of the object (i.e. `copyingfile.mover()`.
You should also rename your classes with PascalCase (first letter uppercase) and remove the parenthesis after `class copyingfiles`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have removed the @staticmethod and renamed my class and remove the parenthesis after class copyingfiles . Now I have another error as, `TypeError: mover() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given
` given self inside.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `@staticmethod` decorator before the definition of `__init__`. When you decorate a method with `@staticmethod`, this method doesn't take the object as implicit first argument (so you shouldn't put `self` in its signature).

For example, below, you can see that both methods are called *without passing any explicit arguments*, even though `A.non_static` requires argument `self`. This is because usual methods receive `self` implicitly, whereas static methods don't.

```py
>>> class A:
...     @staticmethod
...     def static():  # No `self` argument
...         print('static')
...     def non_static(self):  # Here `self` is required
...         print('non-static')

>>> a = A()  # a is an instance of A
>>> a.static()
'static'
>>> a.non_static()
'non-static'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have removed the @staticmethod and renamed my class and remove the parenthesis after class copyingfiles . Now I have another error as, TypeError: mover() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given given self inside.

Answer (score 1):

`__init__` (the constructor) can not be a static method. When you call the constructor of a class `MyClass()` the `__init__` method is called. The `self` is a placeholder argument for the object to which that method belongs - it allows you to access the attributes of that object. But if you make it a `@staticmethod` then `self` is interpreted as a normal argument - which is why you're seeing that `Required 1 argument` error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have removed the @staticmethod and renamed my class and remove the parenthesis after class copyingfiles . Now I have another error as, TypeError: mover() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given given self inside.

Comment: You mover function is defined as `move(self)`. You're calling is as: `testInstance.mover(x,y,z,i)`.  Your method takes only one argument - the first one - which is mapped to the object `testInstance` since it's a class method. But you have given it 4 more arguments: x,y,z,i - hence that error. You need to add those arguments in the method definition too.

Comment: I am sorry I did not understand your point. where do I need to add arguments?

Comment: Where you have defined the method: `def mover(self)` should be `def mover(self, x_arg, y_arg, z_arg, i_arg)`